# Netbeans show method header (Params , Return value) on mouse over

Tags: java, netbeans, ide

From other IDE's i know that i get either Javadoc or at least the Methods header definiton when i hover with mouse across a methods name in form of a tooltip.

```
someClass.someMethod(param1, param2)
```

So hovering across foo would display me the types of param1 and param 2 and the return type if foo has one.

Is this somehow possible in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Netbeans 7.0 or higher

- Hold down `Ctrl` and hover the mouse over the method name. (does not work , if the line has an error).

[image]

- Move the cursor on the method name, and press Ctrl + Shift + Space

[image]

Comment: @Gobliins : Glad you like it :-)

Comment: The `Strg` key is known as the control key `Ctrl` on English keyboards.

Comment: @James : You're right, I forgot to mention that. Thanks +10